# N people are labeled 1 to n and each have a paper with their number on it, put their paper in the bag then randomly pull out a paper from the bag…

Tags: probability

N people are labeled 1 to n. They each have a piece of paper with their number on it.?

They each put their piece of paper in a bag, and then, in turn, pull out one random piece of paper each. What is the probability that no one pulled out their own piece of paper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very famous problem, and goes under different guises.

Have a look at the wikipedia article on [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). You shall get your answer there.

Answer (score 0):

So the actual probability would be $\frac{!n}{n!}$. which converges to $\frac{1}{e}$ as n approaches infinity.